# FMResultSet returning nil in another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, fmdb

I am using FMDB wrapper for my database.I can fetch data using FMResultSet,but when I am trying to return FMResultSet to another ViewController,it returns nil.I am calling my database from here

```
var resultSet: FMResultSet! = db.getUserById(1)
                if(resultSet != nil) {
                    self.setUserInfo(resultSet)
}
```

and here is my database coding part

```
func getUserById(userId: Int) -> FMResultSet {

 let sharedInstance = DatabaseHandler()
 var database: FMDatabase? = nil
 var resultSet: FMResultSet! =  sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_id = ?", withArgumentsInArray: [userId])

    if(resultSet != nil)  {
        while resultSet.next() {
            var name: String = "USER_NAME"
            var location = "USER_LOCATION"
            println("Name: \(resultSet.stringForColumn(name))")
            println("Location: \(resultSet.stringForColumn(location))")
        }
    }

    sharedInstance.database!.close()
    return resultSet
 }
```

When I am printing those values,it shows the values in console,but when I am returning the resultSet,it appears to be nil

What have I done worng?

Comment: No one can help?!I really need this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resultSet is only valid while the database is open. Return something other than the resultSet (i.e., a wrapper object/dictionary/whatever). Generally you iterate the resultSet and pull out what you need and use that. Alternately you hand out the resultSet to the caller and *it* calls `.next` and closes it when done.

Comment: Got your idea,Thanks!I returned class object